# How to render selectable text using PdfDocument

Tags: android, pdfdocument

I am generating a document from a custom model using [PdfDocument](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument) but I am facing two problems:

- the text written is not selectable on the generated pdf, and;
- the pdf size is too big (probably because it renders the layout from the xml as a Bitmap).

Is there any way to solve those two problems **without using a third-party lib**?

Here's an example of how I'm generating a PDF ([medium.com/@strawberryinc0531/…](https://medium.com/@strawberryinc0531/convert-xml-to-pdf-in-android-studio-using-pdfdocument-class-757dee166d50)). I am using Android API 29+ for the tests

Comment: You need to show your code on how you generate the PDF for people to help and what version of Android are you using (because I know there is a bug in early versions - pre Android 6 that meant if bitmaps were used the were uncompressed leading to very large documents).

Comment: @Andrew, here's an example of how I'm generating a PDF (https://medium.com/@strawberryinc0531/convert-xml-to-pdf-in-android-studio-using-pdfdocument-class-757dee166d50). I am using Android API 29+ for the tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the example you give is drawing a view to a bitmap and then adding a bitmap to a pdf, so you will get a pdf with a picture of text that is not selectable.

So that is a really bad example of how to use the PDFDocument class.

You can get a canvas directly from the [PDFDocument page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument.Page#getCanvas()) when you draw a view to this Text will be text and selectable.

A better example of drawing views direct to a PDF is at https://github.com/Zardozz/RecyclerviewPdf

Here it

```
// Get PDF page canvas
Canvas pageCanvas = page.getCanvas();
// Draw current page
parentView.draw(pageCanvas);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this answer \o/. The problem of selecting the text has been solved with it, just the pdf file size now that remains big.

Comment: @Augusto Carmo without sharing you actual code, it's hard to tell what the problem might be, the example given creates a 24 page PDF with 191 text items and icons that is only 136KB, this is a very small PDF

Comment: Thanks again for the reply, @Andrew. I'll double check my code and the images used to check if that's the reason.